# First toggle open by default

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery

So have a block of toggles on my page and now I need to add another block of toggles on the same page but this one with the first toggle active/open by default.
I've been working around the JS but no luck so far so I need your precious help to get this to work.
Thanks!

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpzbh)

**Javascript**

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){

   $('.toggle-view li').click(function () {

        var text = $(this).children('div.toggle-content');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-minus"></i>');    
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-plus"></i>');    
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('activetoggle');

    });
});
```

Comment: I love saying the words _block of toggles_ so I will try to help.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IrobD is this what you need?

Comment: What u mean? Did u make any changes on the code?

Comment: Argh. I forked and saved a version with my change but it retained the same URL. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it with something like:**

```
$('.added_class_on_second li').eq(0).children('.toggle-content').show();
```

Just add another distinct class to the second, or target it with:

```
$('.toggle-view').eq(1).children('li').eq(0).children('.toggle-content').show();
```

if you don't want to change the html at all.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CDdlH

Comment: Thanks this works but I want to have this together with the other block of toggles in the same page.

Comment: they both work in that case... but if you don't want to add a class, then the second line does exactly what you need... updated the pen to show you. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CDdlH

Comment: Almost there ;) however there's a little issue - The open-by-default-block only works if the non open-by-default-block is in the same page. Hope what I'm saying makes sense.
Cheers!

Comment: then you add a distinct class to the one you want to have its first open, like the first example. updated the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CDdlH

Comment: I used `.eq(0)` so that you can change it to be elements other than the first. if that's never the case, then `.first()` could work instead

Answer (score 0):

If you need the first section to be open when the page loads you could simply call `click()` on `$('.toggle-view li').first()`. However, this may have undesired side effects if you have other actions occur on click, and it will perform an animation, so consider creating a function `open` which does nothing but open the indicated section, and calling that on document load.